# Go binary not identified by WebStorm

Tags: go, webstorm

I installed go and ran a hello world from terminal. Now when I try setup Go SDK in WebStorm it fails to identify it.

[image]

The go binary is located in that path and I am able to see it version as well. But WebStorm is not happy for some reason.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Im using below :
Go plugin : 0.10.1726
Mac osx : 10.11.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`webstorm` is not expecting the path to the `go` binary here. Instead, you have to give the path to Go's SDK. On my setup, it is `/usr/lib/golang`.

[image: go plugin]

```
$ ls /usr/lib/golang 
api  bin  favicon.ico  lib  pkg  robots.txt  src  test  VERSION
```

Comment: You were right abt sdk - /usr/local/go is my path : I had to restart webstorm so that it picked it up. Thank you.